# Show Characters shared between two strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, string-comparison

For a Java exercise I'm writing a program where the user enters two strings. The program then checks to see if the two strings share any similar characters and outputs them to the screen.

For example is Terrarium and Terraform are the two strings it should print t e r r a r. However when I run my program it always simply outputs all the characters in the first string. (In this case T e r r a f o r m.)

I suspect I'm creating a logical error based on a limited understanding of loops. But when I search for answers people seem to always use a similar method to my own.

Here is the code for your viewing:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class CountMatches 
  {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println(" Please enter a String >> ");
         String stringA = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println(" Please enter another String >> ");
         String stringB = keyboard.nextLine();

         for(int counter = 0; counter < stringA.length(); counter++ )
         {
            char compareA = stringA.charAt(counter);
            char compareB = stringB.charAt(counter);
            //System.out.println(compareA);
            //System.out.println(compareB);
            //System.out.println("");

            if(compareA != compareB)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            else if(compareA == compareB);
            {
                System.out.println(compareA);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to step through your algorithm with a debugger? That's the best way to find a logical error.

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, it shouldn't print out "t e r r a r", it should print out "t e r r a r m", as they both have an "m" on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if(compareA == compareB);
```

Get rid of the semicolon on this line and it should work.  I would also get rid of the first if statement just keep the second one.

Comment: Thanks don't know why I put the semicolon there.....I had tried multiple combinations of code and was getting tired so it might have been an accident.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with this code.

First,

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter < stringA.length(); counter++ )
```

If the two string are of different length, you could get an exception by going off the end of the other string.  So, do this:

```
int len = stringA.length();
if (len > stringB.lengh()) len = stringB.length();
```

Next, the reason you code fails is because you have a ; at the end of your else.  Your code should be:

```
        if(compareA != compareB)
        {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else // Don't need the == here
        {
            System.out.println(compareA);
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Good luck with this.